# Calling useState hook in child - state data is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm trying to solve an issue with my (fairly simple) React app - so far I have been able to avoid using Redux for global state management by neatly passing data around my components where needed.

I am however running into a major issue: I have components that are shown/hidden using a prop. On the parent level, I use a useState hook as such:

```
const [localOrders, setLocalOrders] = useState([]);
```

I do an HTTP call, and then use `setLocalOrders` and pass in the order data (which is then mapped/displayed on the page and child components). However, I also have a local function that accesses `localOrders`:

```
handleClose: (clearOrder) => {
  setProcessOrderModal({
    ...processOrderModal,
    redacted
  });
  if (clearOrder !== null) {
    setLocalOrders(_.filter(localOrders, ({ order }) => (order.id !== clearOrder)));
  }
},
```

When this code is called in a child component, `localOrders` is empty (set to `[]`). I cannot figure out how to access the actual state data (`localOrders`) which still clearly holds data (like the list of orders on the page is still visible).

Comment: Can you specify a sandbox so we can review all aspects of your code?

Comment: Can you also add the code that shows how you render the child passing the state and handlers as props? This sounds like a problem with memorization of the handler. Are you using any `useCallback` hooks? Also when updating state based on the current state it is better to use the callback version of your state setter function e.g. `setLocalOrders(current => _.filter(current, ...))`.

Comment: Can you add at least add the _.filter function to see what is happening there

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```js
handleClose: (clearOrder) => {

 if (clearOrder) {
    setLocalOrders(state=> _.filter(state, ({ order }) => (order.id !== clearOrder)));
 
 }

  setProcessOrderModal(state => ({
    ...state,
    redacted
  });
  
 }
},
```